# TomEE: javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class javax.ws.rs.core.UriBuilder

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, jax-rs

I am using TomEE 7.0.62 to host a JSP web application.

The server seems to be running perfectly: I used the manager webapp to deploy my own web application, and the home page of the web application displays perfectly.

However, attempting to navigate to other JSP pages produces the following stack trace:

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class javax.ws.rs.core.UriBuilder
org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.doHandlePageException(PageContextImpl.java:916)
org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.handlePageException(PageContextImpl.java:845)
org.apache.jsp.sprint_002dworkload_jsp._jspService(sprint_002dworkload_jsp.java:117)
org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:439)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:395)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:339)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)

root cause

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class javax.ws.rs.core.UriBuilder
com.atlassian.jira.rest.client.internal.async.AsynchronousJiraRestClient.<init>(AsynchronousJiraRestClient.java:45)
com.atlassian.jira.rest.client.internal.async.AsynchronousJiraRestClientFactory.create(AsynchronousJiraRestClientFactory.java:37)
com.atlassian.jira.rest.client.internal.async.AsynchronousJiraRestClientFactory.createWithBasicHttpAuthentication(AsynchronousJiraRestClientFactory.java:42)
com.my_org.jira.reports.JiraReport.createRestClient(JiraReport.java:38)
com.my_org.jira.reports.JiraReport.run(JiraReport.java:42)
org.apache.jsp.sprint_002dworkload_jsp._jspService(sprint_002dworkload_jsp.java:98)
org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:439)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:395)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:339)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
```

I am not sure where to start debugging...this seems to be a simple configuration error, but I don't know how to resolve the package dependencies.

Comment: Type java -version   at the command line, what does it print?

Comment: `java version "1.8.0_60"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_60-b27)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.60-b23, mixed mode)`

Comment: I tried to manually add a `JAR` to `WEB-INF/lib` that contains `javax.ws.rs.core.UriBuilder`, but I am still getting the same error.

Comment: Which file from TomEE website did you download?

Comment: my TomEE download was `apache-tomee-1.7.2-webprofile.tar.gz` from http://tomee.apache.org/downloads.html

Comment: I haven't used TomcatEE. But, now that we know your set up, an expert can advise.

Comment: Looking at http://tomee.apache.org/comparison.html  we can see that the download of TomEE you are using doesn't do RS. Hopefully someone with expertise will post here.

Comment: What do you mean by RS?

Comment: RESTful Web Services

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using the wrong version of TomEE. I was using the light-weight [Web Profile](http://www.apache.org/dyn/closer.cgi/tomee/tomee-1.7.2/apache-tomee-1.7.2-webprofile.tar.gz) edition. I had to switch to the [JAX-RS](http://www.apache.org/dyn/closer.cgi/tomee/tomee-1.7.2/apache-tomee-1.7.2-jaxrs.tar.gz) edition, which supports `javax.ws.rs` (JAX-RS). Once I made that switch, my servlets worked perfectly.